# Why Field declarations have no keywords in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

```js
class MyDemo{
  let x =5;
}
```

We can get an error.  But when we remove the `let` keyword, it would be correct. I want to know why this happend.

Comment: it's how class syntax is **defined**

Comment: It’s simply what the class syntax has been defined as in the specification. Why is it that you need to use the `let` keyword here in this specific syntactic context?

Comment: @Bravo Is there a reference doc to confirm it?

Comment: @awxiaoxian2020 - is there reference doc that describes what you are trying to do? I mean seriously, if there had to be documentation for what NOT to do, the total global storage would not be enough to document what noobies think coding is

Comment: @esqew I'm a beginner of javascript. We know we are required that we should use `let` before the variable when we use it at first. When I use the class in ES6, the keyword "disappeared suddenly". I haven't find any docs yet. I can receive the syntax itself. But I think there should be a note. It's confusing for beginners, I think.

Comment: @Bravo I don't think how to "declare" a variable in class is an abnormal question. Because the usage is common. I only want to know what you said, i.e. `how class syntax is defined ` about this note.

Comment: Class definitions are a specific type of syntax in Javascript.  They have their own rules and those rules require less extra keywords because a class definition has a very limited set of allowable syntax - far, far less than just typing lines of code that will execute.  This is done for convenience since the meaning of what you're typing does not require extra keywords to be clear and specific when in a `class` definition.

Comment: `let` and `const` are used elsewhere to declare a variable within a local scope which is not what you're doing here at all.  Without them, assigning a variable attempts to make a global (or is not allowed in strict mode).  Here you're defining a property that each instantiated object will be given by default (it essentially becomes a hidden/automatic part of the initialization of a new object of this class).  Completely different things - thus different syntax.

Comment: A recommendation.  When learning a new language, it is best to learn what it is and not question why it is not like something else you know.  That will drive you nuts and not be productive at all.  Learn what it is, use what it is, embrace that it is a unique language of its own.  Coming from C++ and learning Javascript, it used to drive me nuts that JS wasn't more like C++.  I now realize all that energy and frustration was completely wasted energy.  Learn what it is and how to best program it and don't try to figure out why it's not like something else you know.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your advice!!! I can ignore why JavaScript isn't like other language but I just want to know how to define the property correctly. There are no reference docs to figure out it, I think it is abnormal.

Comment: What do you mean there are no reference docs?  There's the ECMAScript specification.  There's the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) that is a community driven set of Javascript documentation and browser docuemntation.  There are literally thousands of web sites on every conceivable topic.  There are books.  If I were looking for info on this topic, this [MDN page on the class definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) would be my first stop and sure enough, this is covered there.

Comment: It appears that rather than calling things abnormal, you just need to learn how the Javascript eco-system works and where to find things.  Or buy yourself a set of reference books if that's more your thing.  I gave up on the books along time ago because they immediately get stuck in time and are often out of date by the time they are printed.  But, they work for some.

Comment: My fault. I don't search it carefully. it is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations

Comment: your code has nothing to with `how to "declare" a variable in class` - besides, you don't declare variables in a class, you declare properties or methods - variables are declared inside functions

Comment: actually, to be perfectly accurate, all you deal with for class instances is properties - "method" is just a useful description of a property that happens to be a function - but in reality, all you deal with is properties of the class' prototype

Comment: @Bravo My fault. I modify the title. Now I know that the `property` is diffrent from `variable` . Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let` is used to create a new *standalone identifier* - a variable name. Directly inside a class, assignment is using [class instance field syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) to assign to a property of the instance.

That is, this

```
class MyDemo {
  x = 5;
}
```

means you can then do

```
const demo = new MyDemo();
console.log(demo.x); // logs 5
```

`x` is not a new identifier with a particular block scope - rather, it's a property of the object, so it wouldn't have made sense if the syntax required (or even permitted) them to be preceded by `let` (or `const`).

A property of an object, with a particular configuration (getter, setter, configurable, writable) is a pretty different concept from a standalone identifier (declared with `const`, `let`, or `var`). Mixing the two, like your code does, would just have been too misleading.

Comment: Thanks. But I still think there should be a doc to clarify the variables and properties. After all, We don't need use any keywords for variables and properties in Python and the variables and properties are same declaration in Java. It seems that only JavaScript has adopted this "two different" strategy. and the class is a grammar surger in JavaScript. We should take it more seriously.

Comment: "We don't need use any keywords for variables and properties in Python" — This is not _quite_ correct, since `global` and `nonlocal` keywords exist. Granted, their meaning is completely different, and they are used much less than JavaScript's `const` and `let`.

Comment: `there should be a doc to clarify` - there is - `class` is well documented